# Probability of Rolling a $1$ on an $n$-Die in $r$ Attempts

Tags: probability, summation, dice

I roll an $n$ sided die, numbered $1 \to n$. If I roll a $1$, I walk away; otherwise, I roll the die again. This process could repeat indefinitely.

What is the probability, $P(n,r)$, that I will roll the die no more than $r$ times (walk away in $r$ rolls or fewer)?

---

The probability that I will walk away on (or before?!) the first roll is given by

$$ P(n,1) = \frac{1}{n} $$

On the second roll (assuming I did not roll a 1 on the first roll), there is still a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of walking away; however, because there was a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of walking away on the first roll, calculating P(n,2) is not so simple. Through the analysis of some probability trees, I have come up with the following equation.

$$ P(n,r) = \sum_{i=1}^r\frac{(n-1)^{i-1}}{n^i} $$

---

Is my equation correct? If so, can someone explain how to arrive at this equation logically (without rigorous analysis)?

Comment: It looks correct. Notice this is equal to $(n-1)\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(\frac{n-1}{n})^r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first find the probability that we *do not walk away* in $r$ or fewer rolls. This is the probability of $r$ failures (not $1$) in a row, which is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r$.

It follows that our required probability is $1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^r$.

*Remark:* Your expression is correct. By summing your geometric series, one can get the same answer as the one above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure how to simplify a summation like this. How can I prove $ \sum_{i=1}^r\frac{(n-1)^{i-1}}{n^i} = 1-(\frac{n-1}{n})^r $?

Comment: You are welcome. It is a (finite) geometric series, first term $a=\frac{1}{n}$, common ratio $q=(n-1)/n$. summing from $0$ to $r-1$. Sum is $\frac{a(1-q^r)}{1-q}$. The $1-q$ simplifies to $1/n$, cancelling the $a$, so we just end up with $1-q^r$.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability you roll more than $r$ times? It is equal to the probability you do not roll $1$ in the first $r$ rolls, this probability is $((n-1)/n)^r$.

Therefore the answer is $1-((n-1)/n)^r$